# Upload not working using grive and cron

Tags: bash, cron, centos7, grive

I'm currently running a small database on a centos 7 server.
I've one script for creating backups and another script for uploading them to googledrive using grive. However the script only uploads my files when I run it manually (bash /folder/script.sh). When it is run via crontab the script runs but it wont upload. I cant find any error messages in /var/log/cron or /var/log/messages.

Cron log entry:

```
Dec  7 14:09:01 localhost CROND[6409]: (root) CMD (/root/backupDrive.sh)
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get latest file
file="$(ls -t /backup/database | head -1)"
echo $file

# Upload file to G-Drive
cd /backup/database && drive upload -f $file
```

Answer (score 3):

Add full path to `drive` or add its path to $PATH.

Comment: Thank you! It did the trick to add full path to drive (/usr/local/bin/drive).